# Converting from Gödel code to text

Tags: c#, encryption

I am doing a Gödel encryption software, but I am facing a problem. 
How to get the code after encrypting it? For example, the Gödel number for the symbol `0` is 6 and the Gödel number for the symbol `=` is 5. Thus, in their system, the Gödel number of the formula `0 = 0` is 2^6 × 3^5 × 5^6 = 243,000,000.

Note: 2^6 means 2 in power 6.

```
 //need to make 5+6
        int equalsign = 5;
        int n5 = 2;
        int n6 = 59;
        int final;
        //do caluclations
        final = (Math.Pow(2, 2) * Math.Pow (3, 5) * Math.Pow(5, 59)); 
        Console.WriteLine(final);
```

How to get the `0 = 0` from 243,000,000? I am having problems with this, any suggestion how to make it or for the code?

```
final = (Math.Pow(2, 2) * Math.Pow (3, 5) * Math.Pow(5, 59));
```

This does not work too. Any way how to fix this as well?

This is Gödel formula:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XodCh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to keep dividing the number `final` by the current prime p so long as it is evenly divisble by p. The number of times you can divide evenly by each prime gives you the powers.

roughly speaking you're looking for something like the following pseudocode:

```
code = []
for each prime p:
    c = 0
    while final % p == 0:
         c++
         final = final / p
    code.append(c)
```

Comment: nice, thanks..
but wont that make the process like too long to be compiled. to get the result? it might not be possible to feel it when add those numbers 1 by 1
but, lets say in a db have 500 encrypted data. and it will decrypt all of them before show in.. wont that make it too long?

Comment: Yes this is inefficient. The process of converting the number `final` into the sequence of numbers from the code is exactly integer factorization. There is no known polynomial-time algorithm for this. It's also not encryption so it's better to refer to this process as "decoding" than "decrypting".

Comment: i understand... do you know any way, to make the number/value/string really hard to understand for people, but only the software to understand it? I've tried md5, PAC 2 and some systems like that, but there are many decryption softwares/websites online..

Comment: Actually now that I think about it more deeply I'm not sure it has to be inefficient. The reason is that all of your numbers are of the form 2^(n1)*3^(n2)*5^(n3)... where n1, n2, and the like are all positive, and the size of your alphabet is bounded.... It's actually likely doable in polynomial time.

Comment: the result is really big, for example 2^6 * 3^5* 5^59. result is 1.6666666666666666666E -1 
but how to get the numbers from 16666666666666666666E-1 to that before? this is what I am not finding,

Comment: 2^6 * 3^5* 5^59 is 2697841949839130393229424953460693359375000000. Follow the pseudocode above. Divide by 2 until the number is odd (you can do that 6) times. Divide by 3 until the number isn't evenly divisible by 3 anymore (you can do that 5 times), Divide by 5 until the number isn't evenly divisible by 5 anymore (you can do that 59 times). The result is 6, 5, 59.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was good logic. but.. numbers like this 2697841949839130393229424953460693359375000000 can not be entered in C#
I mean, Int doesnt support for that long, nor Long..

what is the best way to do it? I mean. I can put lower numbers, but that is for "0=0" 
what if there is a name, for example Altjen. the number might be big, and the int/long cant support it that long... how to do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is it possible for an actual code? I was looking at it for around 15 min, did not found a solution.