# Dividing BigInteger in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to divide BigIntegers. 
this is my code so far:

```
BigInteger x = BigInteger.Parse("2697841949839130393229424953460693359375000000");
BigInteger y = BigInteger.Parse("2");
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    double result = Math.Exp(BigInteger.Log(x) / BigInteger.Log(y));
    x = result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

It does the divide. it does it only once. I want to divide the code to minimum it has. it should be 6.

I know that this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++){}
```

is not the right way to do it. does any one know any other way how to?

Comment: I dont understand your problem, it _should_ be doing the calculation 300 times, it's just that it's doing the **exact same thing** 300 times so the result never changes.

Comment: @CodingGorilla `x` changes on each loop so it should produce a different result each time.

Comment: Your code merely does the operation 300 times, you need a while loop to check for that logic.

Comment: I see that you have this nice convenient `Console.WriteLine(result)` in your code.  Maybe you can share some results so that we can see what's happening

Comment: This code won't compile - `result` is `double` and won't assign (directly, without a cast) to `x` (`BigInteger`). Is this the _actual_ code you're having problems with?  With the cast in place, it does [iterate more than once, then throws an exception](http://imgur.com/87xR8DW).

Comment: Well you are storing your result into a double.  Double will reduce your accuracy of the result generally.

Comment: It should be 6 *why*? What calculation are you trying to perform?

Comment: I DID NOT SAY THE CODE WORKS. thats why I am asking here... 
and yes, I know that when I print 300 times the same thing. it will do it

Comment: I did that with Godel formula. 2^6 * 3^5 * 5^6 and the result is that big number. now from that number I Want to get the 6. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062076/converting-from-g%C3%B6del-code-to-text
here is my old post so you can see how I did it.

Comment: @AltjenBerberi nobody said that you said that the code works, but you did say that it divides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember from your other question that you are trying to decode Godel numbers.

You shouldn't stick the result in a double. It's too big. You're looking for BigInteger's [Divide method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divide(v=vs.110).aspx). For your application [DivRem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem(v=vs.110).aspx) is better.

Here's some sample code. It computes 6. This should get you going for the first character. You'll also need to build a list of primes beyond '2' to continue on to the rest of the string.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BigInteger x = BigInteger.Parse("2697841949839130393229424953460693359375000000");
        BigInteger y = BigInteger.Parse("2");

        int counter = 0;
        BigInteger remainder;
        do{
           BigInteger result = BigInteger.DivRem(x, y, out remainder);
           if(!remainder.IsZero)
               break;

           x = result;
           counter++;
        } while (true);

        Console.WriteLine(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you've been really helpful today. thanks Alfred.